# Django DeprecationWarning Use of .. or absolute path

Tags: python, django

I am getting a lot of these warnings in production but not on devstack which is making me curious to know about this warning and how to get rid of this. Apparently there is no information which imports is causing the issue.

I am looking for any tools, documentation that explains this Deprecation warning when this will raise an exception in the future and steps to get rid of this warning.

thank you!

```
[__init__.py:1566] - /edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:1158: DeprecationWarning: Use of .. or absolute path in a resource path is not allowed and will raise exceptions in a future release.
```

Comment: Have you checked the python version on devstack and production?\

Comment: Production is at Python3.5

Comment: and what about devstack ?

Comment: Devstack is also at 3.5, but its strange I am not getting this warning in devstack.

Comment: are django versions also same?

Comment: Yes; django versions are same on prod and on devstack. django 1.11

Comment: Let's wait and see what others have to say

Comment: pkg_resources is part of setuptools. `pip show setuptools` will probably show different versions. It'll also show you which other package requires it (and calls it with an absolute path, triggering the warning). In my case it's google-api-core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that in the code I was using `resource_filename` from `pkg_resources`
` in a way that would raise the warning.

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.resource_filename(resource,'/translations')
```

#### Fix

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.resource_filename(resource,'translations')
```